# Replicar máscara de telefone em vários campos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário que está preenchendo pode incluir vários números de celular, mas a minha função de máscara funciona apenas no primeiro campo.

```
var telMask = ['(99) 9999-99999', '(99) 99999-9999'];
var tel_1 = document.querySelector('#celular');
VMasker(tel_1).maskPattern(telMask[0]);
tel_1.addEventListener('input', inputHandler.bind(undefined, telMask, 14), false);
```

Comment: O problema é que apenas `tel_1` está recebendo o "controle de máscara". Todos os campos de telefone precisam do `addEventListener`

Comment: Mas como eu posso colocar que todos os campos precisam do {addEventListener} se eu não sei a quantidade de campos que vai ter

Comment: Aí você precisa fazer isso via dinamicamente; quando criar um novo campo adiciona o evento nele

Comment: Não tem um outro método além do addEventListener para aplicar aos campos?

Comment: Acontece que você está criando os campos e não adicionado a máscara a eles, entende!?

Comment: Quais bibliotecas estão sendo usadas? eu tenho um que pode atender sua necessidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente colocar a mascara depois que o código carregar, via "Class" do HTML. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```html
<head>
     
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     
    <title>Criando máscaras com jquery</title>
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
     
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("input.fone").mask("(99) 9999-99999");
      });
     
    </script>
    
    <body>
     
      <h1>Usando máscaras com jquery</h1>
     
      <label for="fone">Fone:</label><br>
     
      <input type="text" class="fone" id="fone" name="fone" /><br><br>
    
    </body>
     
    </html>
```

Comment: utilizando o mask do jquery eu consegui fazer, mas tive que colocar com o identificador na classe, utilizando o id não deu certo. Valeu